# IE onpropertychange event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, events

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="select-handler">select</a>
<input type="file" id="real-file-input" style="display:none" />

$('#select-handler').click(function(){
    $('#real-file-input').click(); 
});

$('#real-file-input').bind('propertychange', function(){
    alert('changed');
});
```

it's weird that when I use `.click()` the `propertychange` won't be fired.

Comment: Have you tried this with the .on() method?  According to the docs, it's been the preferred method to use for this purpose since jQuery 1.7.

Comment: @SurrealDreams we are using jQuery 1.4

Comment: Just clicking on an `input type="file"` doesn't change any property, hence [`onpropertychange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx/html) won't be fired.

Comment: @Teemu but then I selected a file, the `value` of the input should be changed, so `onpropertychange` should be fired

Comment: Why not use cross-browser [`onchange`](http://jsfiddle.net/w4kap/1/) instead of IE-only `onpropertychange`?

Comment: cause I have to support IE6

Comment: You can set it in some native way, like set a property, or even inline. IE6 doesn't support `onchange` for `input type="file"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually your code works fine in **IE7 and 8** for me, whenever I change a value of `input type ='file'`, the alert is fired.  Whereas it is not working in **>IE9** versions.

From [**paulbakaus's blog on `propertychange` on Internet Explorer 9**](http://paulbakaus.com/2012/06/14/propertychange-on-internet-explorer-9/)

> What’s wrong with `propertychange` on IE9?
>
> 1. IE9 doesn’t fire non-standard events when binding them through
>      addEventListener. Every modern JS library that uses feature
>      detection, including jQuery, will fail (see also:
>      http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8485). “Not a biggie” you say, “simply
>      use attachEvent directly” you say?
> 2. The good news: propertychange fires when using attachEvent. The bad
>      news: It refuses to fire when modifying any CSS properties on the
>      element that are unknown to the engine.. “Well this sucks,” you say,
>      “but I read you can use DOMAttrModified on IE9!” you say?
> 3. `DOMAttrModified` features exactly the same behavior. It does not fire
>      for unknown CSS properties. This is a complete disaster.

Many developers faces the same weird behavior.

Why do you want to use `onpropertychange` which is supported only by Internet Explorer?

I would rather move on to **`change`** event handler

```
$('#real-file-input').bind('change', function(){
    alert('changed');
});
```

or if it is a **HTML5** then **`input`** event handler.

```
$('#real-file-input').bind('input', function(){
    alert('changed');
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried `change` event first, and it doesn't work in IE6. so my situation is: IE6 + jQuery 1.4

Comment: @wong2 `IE6!!!!!` MS says [GoodBye IE6](http://www.ie6countdown.com/)  Any reason for supporting IE6?

Comment: Change works great for me. Not interested in supporting IE9. Works cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, IE9 doesn't support the "input propertychange" event on deleting. Escape, Delete and Backspace can be easily captured using the "keyup" event with event.which, but the selection of a text and deleting through right click -> delete does not fire the events propertychange, change, select or keyup/keydown.

I found no solution so far for this problem.

here's my code:

```
$('#search_input').on("propertychange input", function(event){
  console.log('propertychange event');
  // trigger search
});
$('#search_input').on("keyup", function(event){
  console.log('keyup event', event.which);
  if(event.which === 27) { // on ESC empty value and clear search
    $(this).val('');
    // trigger search
  } else if(event.which === 8 || event.which === 46) { // trigger search on Backspace
    // trigger search
  }
});
$('#search_input').on("change input", function(event){
  console.log('change event');
  // trigger search
});
$('#search_input').on("select input", function(event){
  console.log('select event');
  // trigger search
});
```